# Is GUI debugging available for embedded languages in DrRacket IDE?

Tags: racket

I am experimenting with Rosette (https://github.com/emina/rosette), an `s-exp` language embedded in racket. I want to step through a rosette program using GUI debugging facilities in DrRacket IDE. However, unlike a racket program, the execution of a rosette program in debug mode doesn't pause at the top-most expression; as soon as I click on the debug button, it runs through to completion. Consequently, I have no way of observing intermediate execution states.

This makes me wonder if DrRacket IDE's debugging facilities are available to embedded `s-exp` languages.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say this, but I don't think there is a way, built in. But DrRacket is very extensible, so I'm guessing there might be a [plugin](http://pkgs.racket-lang.org/).

And feel free to write one!